# Display category and correct date of Wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, getdate

I've had trouble getting the correct date of each post to display. It is displaying the date of the first entry even though I have used 'new WP_Query'.

I also can't get the category type to display.

```
<?php 
$blogloop = new WP_Query( array( 'numberposts' => '3' ) );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $blogloop );
$categories = get_categories( array(
'orderby' => 'name',
 'order'   => 'ASC'
) );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
$category_link = sprintf(
'<a href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ),
esc_html( $category->name )
 );
     echo ' <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
     <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '"><div class="blog-item"><div class="home-blog-img" style="background-image: url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($recent["ID"]).')"></div><div class="home-blog-content"><h3>'. $recent["post_title"] .'</h3><p>'. get_the_date('D M j',$recent) .'</p><span> | </span><p>'. sprintf( esc_html__( 'Category: %s', 'textdomain' ), $category_link ) .'</p></div></div></a></div> ';
}
?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed "ID" in

```
get_the_date('D M j',$recent),
```

Please change it to

```
get_the_date('D M j',$recent["ID"]),
```

so it will display each posts dates